# Align font-awesome icon beside text using css in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists, font-awesome, buddypress

I have tried checking SO but have not found that indirectly address my case. I am working on a WordPress site. I have added icons to the page using its customizer but would need to finish up aligning them. Presently the icons are floating on the text. I can't access the source code, only the customizer I can to finish up the job.

```
This is the main text in a tab I'm adding icons to
<li id="friends-personal-li" class="bp-personal-tab">
    <a href="https://yyyyyy.com/profile/" id="user-friends">Friends<span class="count">2</span></a>
</li>
```

This is the fontawesome icon I'm adding

```
#friends-personal-li:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f0c0";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: blueviolet;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it seems like it should be fine. My guess is there is a broader style affecting the `::before` pseudo element that is causing it to be positioned over your text. Perhaps a custom bullet for an `li`?

Use the browser's developer tools to right-click "inspect" the element and see what styles are being applied to the `li` an the `::before`. If you find it override it within your selector above.

Comment: You are right. I added another CSS style to align it. It's fine now.

Comment: That's great to hear. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```css
#friends-personal-li{
  position: relative;
}
#friends-personal-li:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f0c0";
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: blueviolet;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -3ch;
}
```

If you are trying to do something like this[image: Friends 2]

If you make the parent item `position: relative;` then you can easily place the `:before` element using `absolute` and reference the parent item.